# What is the difference between $T^\mu{}_\nu$ and $T_\nu{}^\mu$?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, notation, linear-algebra, covariance

I do understand why the horizontal order matters for indices on the same vertical position, e.g.:

$$T\left(V_{(1)},V_{(2)}\right) = T_\color{red}{\mu\nu}V^\mu_{(1)}V^\nu_{(2)} \neq T_\color{red}{\nu\mu}V^\mu_{(1)}V^\nu_{(2)} = T\left(V_{(2)},V_{(1)}\right)$$

But I don't understand why $T^\mu{}_\nu \neq T_\nu{}^\mu$ in general. The way I see it, both are linear maps from a vector and a dual vector to $\mathbb{R}$. The horizontal order of the indices shouldn't matter because the vertical position already specifies whether it refers to the vector index or the dual vector index:

$$T(\omega,V) = T^\color{red}\mu{}_\color{red}\nu \omega_\mu V^\nu = T_\color{red}\nu{}^\color{red}\mu \omega_\mu V^\nu = T(\omega,V)$$

Comment: Just to clarify, I assume you don't have the stress-energy tensor in mind -- that was what I initially assumed from your notation.

Comment: @BenCrowell Correct. I should have been more careful with the notation. But $T^\mu{}_\nu \neq T_\nu{}^\mu$ for the stress-energy tensor too, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$T^\mu{}_\nu$ and $T_\nu{}^\mu$ are both maps from a vector and a dual vector to $\mathbb R$, true. But they aren't necessarily the *same* map as each other.

Mathematically, you can see this by considering the difference explicitly:

$$ T^\mu{}_\nu-T_\nu{}^\mu $$

You can use the metric to raise/lower one of the indices, like $T^\mu{}_\nu=g_{\rho\nu}T^{\mu\rho}$. If you do this for both, you get:

$$ T^\mu{}_\nu - T_\nu{}^\mu=g_{\rho\nu}\left(T^{\mu\rho}-T^{\rho\mu}\right)$$

Which shows that the reason $T^\mu{}_\nu\ne T_\nu{}^\mu$ is the same as why $T^{\mu\nu}\ne T^{\nu\mu}$ in general.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is $(T^{\mu\rho}-T^{\rho\mu})g_{\rho\nu}$.

Comment: I meant conceptually, not literally $T^\mu{}_\nu - T_\nu{}^\mu$. But now I'm intrigued. Where did that expression come from? Would you mind elaborating on your answer?

Comment: @Wood Contraction that raises or lowers an index doesn't change the order of the indices. For non-symmetric tensors, this is the only way to make certain differences clear. For symmetric tensors,  you'll sometimes see the indices at the same horizontal position because the order stops mattering. The obvious example is contracting two metrics to get a Kronecker delta.